# How do I place shadow under XUL popup panel

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xul

I'm trying to place a shadow under a popup panel that defined as follows:

```
<popupset id="mainPopupSet">
    <panel id="autoTagBookmarksPopup" noautohide="true" fade="none" backdrag="true" level="float">
        <hbox id="titleBox">
            <spacer flex="1"/>
            <image id="closeImage" align="end"/>
        </hbox>
```

...
I wasn't succesful with the: box-shadow

any one has sugestions?

Comment: Here : http://www.xul.fr/en/css/box-shadow.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623609/can-i-have-an-xul-panel-without-a-shadow-in-my-firefox-extension

Comment: http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=4wjk7x_4Un7zQTxqquOTMKdIQww&cid=wZKBjpj2Txs&s=&browser=Default#L0

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the css that you were using for box-shadow?

Try this...

```
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;

/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

Comment: Tried both: 
`#autoTagBookmarksPopup{
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;

    -moz-box-shadow: default;
    box-shadow: 10px, 10px, 5px, black;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: aqua;
    -moz-border-top-colors: aqua;
    -moz-border-left-colors: aqua;
    -moz-border-right-colors: aqua;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;

    /*padding: 300px, 300px, 300px, 300px;*/
    /*margin: 100px, 100px, 100px, 100px;*/

    background-color: white;
    /*opacity: 0.95;*/
}`

Comment: #mainPopupSet {box-shadow: 10px, #000}

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I had the same issue and want to share my solution so this might be of any help for others.

I have not found a way to place the box-shadow on a panel directly. It seems, that everything visually outside the panel element will be cutted (the shadow is placed outside).

However I then defined the shadow for the first child and added some margin so the shadow will be visible.

For the given example, this might look something like this (untested):

```
panel#autoTagBookmarksPopup {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
}

panel > hbox#titleBox {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #888;
}
```